# Getting net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE randomly at times

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

I am using jsp with spring mvc without springboot along with plain css, bootstrap4 and jquery. The java application has several pages, each mapped to a backend route and the application works without errors sometimes but other times I get **net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** on 1 or 2 files or even the backend url that serves the web page. **The same error appears on firefox, chrome and edge randomly. In chrome, i have already tried deleting history and cache, running on incognito mode**. Attached the error snippets below for reference:

**1. Failed URL**

[image]

**2. Failed resource (css)**

[image]

This does not seem like an application level issue but likely a server issue as tomcat server does not send few file but this is my speculation and can't base it on actual facts.

The application is deployed on **tomcat 8.5**. There are more applications that are deployed on the same windows server with tomcat service. I am not knowledgeable in web service configuration so do I need to change some configuration for tomcat or can it be another issue entirely?

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.